# Multiline regular expressions with python requests module

Tags: python, regex, python-requests

I am iterating over a web page line by line using requests, but trying to capture some multi-line regular expressions:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url)

for line in r.iter_lines(): 
    pat = re.search(regex, line)
    if pat:
        print pat.group(1)
```

I have tried concatenating the whole file into one long string, but that seems wrong.

What is the best way to capture these multiline expressions (preferably using requests)?

Note: I am new to requests. I have looked at the docs but haven't found, or understood, the answer.

Thanks

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the edit. Beat me to it.

Comment: I don't see what you think `requests` has to do with this problem. Iterating line by line over _anything_ means you only have one line at a time, which means your can't do multiline regexp searches; whether it's a local file, a page returned by `requests`, or a list of strings doesn't really matter.

Comment: @abarnert Yes. Replacing r.iter_lines() with r.text works, as per Rob's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = requests.get(url)
pat = re.search(regex, r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks. Working as: re.search(regex, r.text, re.DOTALL)